# Nested ANOVAs in R vs Averaging Data Points

Tags: r, anova, nested-data

I am working on a problem involving subject workload in different conditions. During my experiment each subject only experiences 1 condition (out of 3 possible conditions). They complete 7 trials and each trial has a workload measure assosiated with it. I have 10 subjects per condition (30 subjects total, 210 trials total).

I originally was planning on doing a nested ANOVA, where condition is fixed and subject ID is nested within condition. When doing this in R I get the following result:

[image: nested anova]

The values on condition are very significant. However, if I take each subject and average their workload score (so that I now have 10 data points per condition, 1 per subject) and run a 1 factor ANOVA I get the following result:

[image: 1 factor anova]

This is not significant. It seems weird that there is this big of a difference in the p-values.

I dug into the R code and it seems like the nested anova is calculating the F value for condition as `condition MSE/ residual MSE` , when it should be `condition MSE/ subject in Condition MSE`  [based on https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/ppc/section2/ppc233.htm]. If I do the latter, it gives me the exact same result as the subject average ANOVA results.

I have two questions from this.

- If the subject average and nesting give the same ANOVA results, what is the benefit of nesting?
- Which is the correct method to calculate the nested ANOVA F value, the one in R or the one from NIST?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, i may have the same concern. By testing the main factor in your case as F(Condition) = MS(Condition)/MS(Residuals), one doesnt know whether the result supports extra variation in Condition or Condition:SubjectID (or both). Your cited source says i think correctly, instead test F(Condition) = MS(Condition)/MS(Condition:SubjectID). That way even with extra var due to Condition:SubjectID the test only supports an extra effect due to Condition. This is how i learnt it in Sokal and Rohlf (1995. Biometry). My work-around in R has been (using your (sub)group names) to generate a summary table via:

```
s <- summary(aov(WeightedTotal ~ Condition/SubjectID, data=WL))
f <- s[[1]][[3]][[1]]/s[[1]][[3]][[2]]
p <- pf(f, s[[1]][[1]][[1]], s[[1]][[1]][[2]], lower.tail = FALSE)
s[[1]][[4]][[1]] <- f
s[[1]][[5]][[1]] <- p
s
```

I think this solves your problem, but not our wider concern: Why does the most commonly recommended model in aov() for a single-level nested one-way anova test the main factor against the residuals and not the subgroup?